# I am converting excel sheet to JSON objects. While converting date from excel is giving me some random numbers. How to convert it to date in JSON

Tags: javascript

In excel i gave the date as `22/03/2019` in conversion to json i am getting as below.

`"receivedDate": 43546`

how do i get the original format?

```
var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

resultJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: true });
```

`resultJson` contains the output data. I need output as `22/03/2019`

Comment: Pasrse it as `string`. Json does not support date

Comment: @SaiSurya I'm facing the same issue. Did it get resolved? Could you pls tell me?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, try doing the following.

Change your workbook variable from:

```
var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
```

to:

```
var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
                type: "binary", cellDates: true, dateNF: 'mm/dd/yyyy;@'
            });
```

I have given a sample date format, change the format as required.

Thanks.

Comment: ` type: "binary", cellDates: true, dateNF: 'mm/dd/yyyy;@'` helped me

Answer (score 1):

```
var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

resultJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {dateNF:'mm/dd/yyyy;@',cellDates:true, raw: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue while working with Javascript using playwright

```
npm install -s excel-date-to-js
```

```
const { getJsDateFromExcel } = require("excel-date-to-js");

async ExcelDateToJSDate(formatDate) {
        const convDate = getJsDateFromExcel('42510');
       //output will be  2016-05-20T00:00:00.000Z
      // now covert it to get date 20/05/2016
        const inputDate = new Date(convDate);
        const updatedDate = inputDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
        return updatedDate;

     }
```